# HTML5 iPhone Button Click/Touch-Eventr?

Tags: iphone, html

how can I catch the touch or click-event on a button from an iPhone or any other smartphone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<button type="button" onclick="do something">Click Me!</button>
```

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that the type-attributes is required.